# Revision/HEAD as parameter to TortoiseIDiff

Tags: command-line, tortoisesvn, compare, winmerge

I'm trying to make Notepad++ automatically launch Tortoise's Diff.

With WinExplorer's context menu itens, Tortoise does it nicelly. I use WinMerge to compare and merge files and it's executed. But I can't find a command line way for Tortoise to do the same.

I found `http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation-idiff.html` but it was no use. What I need to do is Tortoise to create a temp file with HEAD copy of the file I wanna compare and execute WinMerge passing these files as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvm I got it!

`TortoiseProc /command:diff /path:"$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

And I can even create a shortcut to run it :D